# Why the azure endpoints are closed?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

[image]I have a classic Azure virtual machine. I recently created internet facing endpoints, but they seem to be closed so i am not able to connect to the VM from the internet. I tried creating other endpoints, but all are closed.

The selected port in the image given below is the one i have created but its closed when i check it online with this tool http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "they seem to be closed." Please edit your question to 1) show your endpoint setup, including "other endpoints" you refer to and 2) show some type of evidence (logs/errors/etc) that explains/shows the issue you're having. Without more info, there's not much to help with.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Hey I have edited the question.

Comment: When you try a remote desktop connection, are you trying to connect on port `54318` or on port `3389` ? Regardless: This should be posted to ServerFault, not StackOverflow.

Comment: I am able to do the remote desktop connection. The port 8818 which has been created is to access the SQL server from clients over the internet and the port is closed.